# Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException with message 'Expected response code "250" but got an empty response.'

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I'm using Google Workspace SMTP relay service to send emails from my Laravel app. It has been working well for over more than a year now, but I'm not sure what exactly stopped it from working.
When I try to send an email I get the following error:

```php
>>> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::to('myemail@gmail.com')->send(new App\Mail\CourseEnrolmentEmail($user, App\Course::first()));

// The error
Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException with message 'Expected response code "250" but got an empty response.'
```

I suspect it is related to my upgrade from Laravel 8 to Laravel 9, but not sure how to fix it.

My `mail.php`

```php
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
        ],
```

My mail config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Name"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myaddress@workspace.com
```

*I'm authenticating via IP, so the password and username fields are not required*

My GSuite Gmail routing configuration 
[image: Gsuite Gmail routing config]

**Note**
In the above config, I have tried checking TLS and also changing Allowed senders to "Only Registered Apps users in my domains" but the problem still persists.

I have tried suggestions from

1. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-swift-mailer-exception-expected-response-code-250-but-got-an-empty-response-using-gmail-smtp-relay-database-queue-driver
2. [Laravel 9 - Infomaniak : Expected response code "250" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833122/laravel-9-infomaniak-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-550-with-m)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283422/11752623
4. https://www.cubebackup.com/blog/how-to-use-google-smtp-service-to-send-emails-for-free/ Method 3

All of them were not successful. I appreciated your help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution,
I went to `vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/SmtpTransport.php` under the assertResponseCode method. I echoed the response which showed the following:

```
421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO) r29-200a50c01d0000xxxxxxxxxxxx87edb.28 - gsmtp
```

More details about the error from [google documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en)

The issue was that Swift Mailer was using 127.0.0.1 as the domain for sending the mail which was unknown to Gmail.

So, the solution was to set my domain name in the `config/mail.php` file

```php
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN', 'mydomain.com')//this line here
        ],
```

More info:

1. https://insights.rytass.com/gmail-smtp-relay-421-4-7-0-try-again-later-closing-connection-ehlo-cfcdac3cf9c7
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/929559/postfix-error-421-4-7-0-try-again-later-closing-connection-ehlo